# What is the purpose of _IOR_BAD and _IOW_BAD?

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, ioctl

The kernel header file with the definitions for defining ioctl functions, [/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctl.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/ioctl.h#L72), has the usual and commonly applied macros `_IO`, `_IOR`, `_IOW`, and `_IOWR`.  Right beside those, there are a few more macros with `_BAD` suffixes which I am curious about.

```
 /* used to create numbers */
 #define _IO(type,nr)            _IOC(_IOC_NONE,(type),(nr),0)
 #define _IOR(type,nr,size)      _IOC(_IOC_READ,(type),(nr),(_IOC_TYPECHECK(size)))
 #define _IOW(type,nr,size)      _IOC(_IOC_WRITE,(type),(nr),(_IOC_TYPECHECK(size)))
 #define _IOWR(type,nr,size)     _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE,(type),(nr),(_IOC_TYPECHECK(size)))
 #define _IOR_BAD(type,nr,size)  _IOC(_IOC_READ,(type),(nr),sizeof(size))
 #define _IOW_BAD(type,nr,size)  _IOC(_IOC_WRITE,(type),(nr),sizeof(size))
 #define _IOWR_BAD(type,nr,size) _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE,(type),(nr),sizeof(size))
```

The Linux cross reference services show **no** usage of them.  [Googling](https://www.google.com/#q=_IOWR_BAD+OR+_IOR_BAD+OR+_IOW_BAD&safe=off) turns up about a dozen Linux kernel cross reference sites, but absolutely no usage.

What is the intent of these macros?  They look like they work the same way as the non-`_BAD` macros.  Maybe someone knows their history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very old code: http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/0310.1/0019.html

> **From: Maciej Zenczykowski** 
>   **Date: Wed Oct 08 2003 - 05:03:01 EST**
>
> > Maybe I got something wrong, but could someone please help me to
> >     understand why introduce _IOR_BAD here? Thanks first! :)
>
> So as not to break userspace we must still support old values, at the
>   same  time we want new programs to start using the new correct values
>   - hence  the introduction of *backward compatibility* values.

And in general, the search terms you are probably looking for is [`_IOR_BAD lkml`](https://www.google.com/search?q=_IOR_BAD+lkml)

Comment: Oh wow!:  That is over ten years ago!  Thanks for finding that.

Comment: Also, note that this is now part of the public API, so it is likely to remain in this file forever.